# construct regex to select only filepath from string

Tags: regex

I have big text with  file-paths and additional infos

```
msmdsrvi.rll    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Analysis Services\AS OLEDB\110\Resources\1049  1,12 MB 31.07.2015 5:56:58
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Excel.Common.FrontEnd.resources.dll  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\ADDINS\PowerPivot Excel Add-in\ar    2,05 MB
```

would like construct regex that ommit first word *filename*  select full filepath with filename and omit all other after it 
I'm looking for some online regex helper or a good hand.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this two are the best online regex testers...

1. https://regexr.com/
2. https://regex101.com/

They explain step by step!